# Difference between "tangible" and "perceptible"

Tags: word-choice

As defined in the Cambridge dictionary, booth "[tangible](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/tangible)" and "[perceptible](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perceptible)" seem to be interchangeable and quite similar in meaning.

Would you agree ?

Comment: I think *tangible*, when talking about sensory evidence, is much more often used of *touchable with one’s hands*, and *perceptible* for the more remote senses (sight, sound, smell). Due to this, the metaphoric senses differ as well: *tangible* means *real*, *concrete*, *indisputable*, and *perceptible* means either *just perceptible*, a kind of liminal sense something is there, or a big spike in perceptabilty: something that would draw your attention. Not *shocking*, but definitely *noticeable*.

Comment: I came across this in a definition of "goods" or "commodities". EG. A  item/property/thing which is perceptible or tangible.

Comment: You mean *commodities*? In that case its differentiating from a *service*: a service is an action performed for your benefit or on your behalf: it can be described by a *verb*. A good or commodity, on the other hand, is a concrete, physical *thing*, and can be described by as *noun*. The phrasing *tangible or perceptible* is a little pleonastic, but if it helps you can think of *tangible* as *amenable to touch* and *perceptible* as *amenable to seeing, hearing, smelling, or tasting*, and together *tangible or perceptible* mean any of those, so *can be sensed*, ie *a real thing*.

Comment: Yes, I agree complete so far.

Comment: Well, there you are then. They’re not interchangeable but they are conceptually related.

Comment: There's an inclusion relationship - something can be perceptible without being tangible, but something tangible must be perceptible.

Comment: This reminds me of some other expressions out of my product politic study. 1. haptic (touchable) (haptic stimulus)  2. olfactory (to smell)